# Modify current environment within python script

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I would like to create a python tool for dynamically setting up my environment. I would like to be able to do the following.

```
$ echo $FOO

$ ./foo.py
$ echo $FOO
bar
```

If this is possible I would greatly appreciate assistance getting this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible (because the Python process has its own environment).  You can (though it might not be worthwhile) write a script whose *output* is commands for `bash`, and then write `eval "$(./foo.py)"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought. Thanks for confirming, I guess it is time for me to learn bash.

Comment: If, say, it's always (and only) `FOO` you want to modify, you can write `export FOO=$(./foo.py)` and not learn any more `bash`.